# Is -allObjects on NSMutableSet thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, nsmutableset

The documentation on NSSet objectEnumeration [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/objectEnumerator):

> When this method is used with mutable subclasses of NSSet, your code shouldn’t modify the set during enumeration. If you intend to modify the set, use the allObjects method to create a “snapshot” of the set’s members. Enumerate the snapshot, but make your modifications to the original set.

Now my question is: **Is the allObjects method itself thread safe?**

I have implemented an operation set like so:

```
@interface OperationSet : NSObject
@end
@implementation OperationSet
{
    NSMutableSet *_set;
}
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)addOperation:(Operation *)operation
{
    if (operation)
    {
        [_set addObject:operation];
    }
}
- (void)removeOperation:(Operation *)operation
{
    if (operation)
    {
        [_set removeObject:operation];
    }
}
- (void)removeAllOperations
{
    [_set removeAllObjects];
}
- (void)enumerateWithOperationBlock:(OperationBlock)block
{
    NSArray *allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    [allObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Operation *o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        block(o);
    }];
}
- (void)flushCompletedOperations
{
    NSArray *allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    NSSet *safeSet = [NSSet setWithArray:allObjects];
    NSSet *completed = [safeSet objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(Operation *o, BOOL *stop){
        return o.completed;
    }];
    [_set minusSet:completed];
}
- (NSUInteger)count
{
    return [_set count];
}
- (BOOL)any:(OperationAnyBlock)block
{
    NSArray *allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    NSUInteger index = [allObjects indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Operation *o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return block(o);
    }];
    return (index != NSNotFound);
}
- (Operation *)getOperationWithMatchingData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    NSArray *allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    NSUInteger index = [allObjects indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Operation *o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [o matchesData:data];
    }];
    return (index == NSNotFound ? nil : allObjects[index]);
}
@end
```

This all works fine.
But I have got a crash via Crashlytics, which is rare (two out of hundreds), but is there:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018772c438 -[__NSSetM addObject:] + 448
1  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018772c430 -[__NSSetM addObject:] + 440
```

The OperationSet is accessed from multiple threads.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks dasblinkenlight for enlighting the allObjects usage.
I have edited my implementation like so:

```
@interface OperationSet : NSObject
@end
@implementation OperationSet
{
    NSMutableSet *_set;
    dispatch_queue_t _queue;
}
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        _queue = dispatch_queue_create("OperationQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)addOperation:(Operation *)operation
{
    if (operation)
    {
        dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
            [_set addObject:operation];
        });
    }
}
- (void)removeOperation:(Operation *)operation
{
    if (operation)
    {
        dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
            [_set removeObject:operation];
        });
    }
}
- (void)removeAllOperations
{
    dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
        [_set removeAllObjects];
    });
}
- (void)enumerateWithOperationBlock:(OperationBlock)block
{
    __block NSArray *allObjects;
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    });
    [allObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Operation *o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        block(o);
    }];
}
- (void)flushCompletedOperations
{
    __block NSArray *allObjects;
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    });
    NSSet *safeSet = [NSSet setWithArray:allObjects];
    NSSet *completed = [safeSet objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(Operation *o, BOOL *stop){
        return o.completed;
    }];
    [_set minusSet:completed];
}
- (NSUInteger)count
{
    return [_set count];
}
- (BOOL)any:(OperationAnyBlock)block
{
    __block NSArray *allObjects;
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    });
    NSUInteger index = [allObjects indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Operation *o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return block(o);
    }];
    return (index != NSNotFound);
}
- (Operation *)getOperationWithMatchingData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    __block NSArray *allObjects;
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    });
    NSUInteger index = [allObjects indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Operation *o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [o matchesData:data];
    }];
    return (index == NSNotFound ? nil : allObjects[index]);
}
@end
```

The code works! Which is a good sign, but can you please review it?

And there is another question: **Is there any difference in using allObjects versus making a set copy?**

That is using this code:

```
- (void)enumerateWithOperationBlock:(OperationBlock)block
{
    __block NSArray *allObjects;
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        allObjects = [_set allObjects];
    });
    [allObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Operation *o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        block(o);
    }];
}
```

over this code:

```
- (void)enumerateWithOperationBlock:(OperationBlock)block
{
    __block NSSet *safeSet;
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        safeSet = [_set copy];
    });
    [safeSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Operation *o, BOOL *stop) {
        block(o);
    }];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutableSet` is **not** thread-safe. If you wish to access one from multiple threads, you must enforce one-at-a-time access yourself.

This is documented in [“Thread Safety Summary” in the *Threading Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html).

The typical way to enforce one-at-a-time access is by creating one GCD queue (for each set) and accessing the set only from that queue (using `dispatch_sync` or, if possible, `dispatch_async`).  In your example, you would add a `dispatch_queue_t` instance variable to your class, initialize it in`init`, and use it in each of your other instance methods.

Comment: @rob-mayoff I have a similar issue that I haven't found a way to implement a GCD queue for (I'm using a lock now).  I have a class that acts as a wrapper for a C++ vector.  It has methods that add elements (push onto the vector) -easy to queue this. However, I also need regular access to the vector pointer directly in some math-heavy methods in another class in a background thread (think tic-toc write/read).  Right now my solution is to have the pointer getter lock the class (so new data is added to a temp array) and the math-heavy method call unlock when done. How would I use a queue here?

Comment: @Adam You should post a new question, not a comment on my answer.

Comment: @robmayoff done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435895/enforcing-one-at-a-time-access-to-pointer-from-a-primative-wrapper

Answer (score 2):

`NSMutableSet` is [listed among the classes that are not thread-safe](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html), so its methods should be considered non-thread safe unless explicitly documented otherwise (none of the `NSMutableSet` methods are documented as thread-safe at this time).

I think that by

> use the `allObjects` method to create a “snapshot”

they meant creating a snapshot behind a lock, to avoid holding a lock on the entire set during the entire time that it takes you to enumerate its objects, and perform operations on them.

Answer (score 1):

Your other question: [mySet allObjects] returns an NSArray containing all the objects in the set, while [mySet copy] returns an NSSet. If you don't need the properties of a set (very fast test for membership), an NSArray will probably be a bit quicker.